# UDP Packet drop?

Tags: linux, networking, udp

Multicast packet got drop between the server, multicast work on udp which unreliable so drop packet is expected

Question:
is their a way or utility available to capture udp packet at  os kernel level ?

Answer (score 1):

The question is yet rather unclear, but if you are after a UDP packet capture tool on Linux you can use `tcpdump` which should be either installed by default with your distribution or in your distribution's repositories.

Example to capture all UDP packets that a host has visibility (use it as root or with sudo to see all packets, even those not intended to your host but that are "passing by"):

```
tcpdump -i <net_interface> -vv udp
```

Replace `<net_interface>` by eth0, p1p1, ens32, etc. what ever is your current network interface.

You can use the `-w <file>` switch to store the packets in a file for reading later with tcpdump or wireshark (a GUI tool).

Comment: I'd write `-Uw <file>` such that you don't see partial packets if you try to read the file, while it is still being written to.

Comment: Correct @kasperd It is a bit more I/O intensive than without `-U` so I often prefer without the -U, wait for things to happen, stop the trace and then look at it. But you are right that if I/O sensitivity is not a concern then it is really interesting to use the -U modifier.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to UDP capture on Linux server you use following.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931746/how-can-i-use-tcpdump-on-unix-to-view-messages-sent-to-a-specific-multicast-addr

```
tcpdump -nqi eth0 -s0 -w /tmp/$HOSTNAME-udp-trace.pcap
```

netstat command in loop on both the server:

```
while true; do date >> /tmp/netstat_-s-$HOSTNAME.out.txt; netstat -s >> /tmp/netstat_-s-$HOSTNAME.out.txt; sleep 1; done
```